# Did Audience Builder and Contact Builder merge?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

I would like to know if it is necessary to contract it apart from Contact Builder or now is integrated with Data Designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact Builder is responsible for aggregating customer data from multiple source into a single customer view, known as the contact model in marketing cloud. For more information refer to the [official documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/).

Audience Builder is a segmentation tool, that abstracts the traditional SQL process for building segments and allows marketers to build segments by dragging and dropping them. For more information, please refer to the the [documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/audience_builder/).

Contact Builder has been moved to the Audience Builder tab as shown below

[image]

You do not need to have Audience Builder provisioned to use Contact Builder.

**In addition, their functionality remains different (i.e Audience Builder features are not available within Contact Builder)**

Comment: Ok, but what about Audience Builder features? are all now in Contact Builder? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I will update my answer no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Audience Builder is the most elaborate, out-of-the-box segmentation tool that Salesforce Marketing Cloud offers. Audience Builder also features a drag and drop interface, just like data filters – but, what makes it different, is that it also has the capability to filter across data extensions and append data to audiences. These Audiences* are also static in nature, which means that you need to refresh them daily to keep them up to date.

*in Audience builder, segments are called ‘Audiences’.